# Design pattern for the multimodel analysis of data in c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a question specifically about designing good *repeatable* and *expandable* code that allows for the analysis of of a particular type (that will remain constant). I am aiming for a design pattern similar to the *decorator* but it doesn't need to be as complex.

**The case study**

I have a clustering algorithm that will identify several different point cloud clusters in a set of dense laser data. This is not important to the question but provides a good background for the problem. The issue is that I know one and only one of the clusters is a particular object that I want to do work on. This can be a different object in different scenarios and so I want to be able to create the clustering class where the user can specify their own functions for identifying this. These functions can take the following form:

1. Analysis of the centroid of the data. Position? Does it fall in an exclusion zone?
2. Analysis of the point cloud. How big is it, which way does it point, what do the normals look like.
3. There is the possibility that the user might want to analyze all of the point clouds before deciding which one. For example in the above case study one of the functions might be `bool doesItHaveTheMostPoints(PointCloud)` which would be difficult to evaluate unless you looped over the clusters twice.

Comment: IMHO the better destination for your question is [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: _@Ben_ Hint: That's not really the way to provide canonicals. You'll catch them while flying out usually (the usual pattern is _short question_, long/many answers). It's a hard task to write them in advance (at least with a missing answer). If you think, what I wrote doesn't apply, just forget what I wrote.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am not 100% sure I understand what you wrote. Do you have an idea of a better way to implement the added functionality?

Comment: _@Ben_ _'I am not 100% sure ...'_ then I think my disclaimer applies, just forget about it. I thought, you wanted to establish a canonical Q&A about this topic. If not, I really think your more comfy home will be [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So what about if I removed the current solution section and posted it as the first answer. Would that suit the site rules better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The current solution**

Currently I have developed a method to allow users to add functions to the class that will be used. These functions are specific to either the centroid, or to the point cloud.

Here is a simple example illustrating how:

```
 // Some functions that can be used to analyse the data. 
 bool is3(int value) {
     if (value == 3)
         return true;
     return false;
 }

 bool ismodulo3(int value) {
     if (value % 3 == 0)
         return true;
     return false;
 }

 // The extractor class
 class A {
     public:

     //Added data analysis functions go into a vector.
     void addFunctionPointer(bool (*function)(int)) {
         functions.push_back(function);
     }

     // Here the functions would be evulated to determine if the 
     // data is what we want.
     void print(void) {
         for (int i = 0; i < functions.size(); ++i)
         {
             std::cout << "Function: " << i << " evalutes: " 
                 << functions[i](value) << std::endl;
         }
     } 

     // The data being analysed.
     int value;
     // The functions stored to analyse it. 
     std::vector<bool (*)(int)> functions;
 };

 // A simple example implementation.
 int main() {
     A a;
     a.value = 6;
     a.addFunctionPointer(&is3);
     a.addFunctionPointer(&ismodulo3);
     a.print();
 }
```

The downsides of this are:

- I find that it is not easy readable and the intention of the code is not particularly clear without explanation.
- The current solution doesn't deal well with the possibility that the user might want to analyse all of the point clouds before deciding which one. For example in the above case study one of the functions might be bool doesItHaveTheMostPoints(PointCloud) which would be difficult to evaluate in the above solution because there would need to be some level of stored memory.